# Does the f-string change inserted value in it?

Tags: python, f-string, objectid

This code prints the values of **a** and **b** while both refer to the ID of the wrapper's ID,and both return same ID.

```
def my_decorator(func):

    def wrapper():
        pass

    return id(wrapper)

def some_func():
    pass

a = id(my_decorator(some_func))  
b = id(my_decorator(some_func))

print(a)
print(b)    # both return same ID
```

Than I'm inserting the values of **a** & **b** into f-string and code returns different IDs.

```
a = f"foo - { id(my_decorator(some_func)) }"
b = f"foo - { id(my_decorator(some_func))} "
print(a)
print(b)   # return diff IDs
```

Why?

Comment: Short form: you're bypassing an optimization that the language spec neither guarantees nor forecloses. This is thus undefined behavior and subject to change at any time. _As_ undefined behavior, I don't believe documenting it here is worth doing: anyone who writes code that depends on things not given in the language spec is living in a state of sin.

Comment: Why would you think they should be the same, *especially* since your f-strings aren't (quite) the same?

Comment: @ Scott Hunter  1:Cause I think they both refer to same object in the memory.2.The first variant is code returns same IDs and that's asserts my opinion.

Comment: @ Scott Hunter Diff strings are my bad,but that's doesn's affect to main question.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I really appreciate your attention and answer,but I can not get your approach,can u provide me relevant  article?

Comment: @cardinal2000 They are not the same, you are taking `id(id(x))`, but in python integers with the same value are not always the same object.

Comment: @ mousetail Your answer is partial right, cause of in this case your noticed behavior doesn't make sense, the value of variables doesn't changing cause of id() rather the f-string.

Comment: Did you mean to return `id(func)` instead of `id(wrapper)`. The wrapper closure will create a new function each time

Comment: It changes because you're calling `my_decorator` twice, not because of f-string.

Comment: @Mark Ransom So how u can explain the first case behavior with using only id() without f-string?It returns same ID everytime.

Comment: I believe, In your first case, the execution is so fast that the object created earlier is not garbage collected by the time second call is made. See the second screenshot in the answer I have posted. There are two different ids for the first two calls.

Comment: Try `a = id(my_decorator(some_func));
print(a);
gc.collect();
b = id(my_decorator(some_func));
print(b)` for demonstration. As the answer explains: it's an internal optimisation, and basically a coincidence; not a language rule.

Comment: @9769953 there is no such func 'gc.collect()' in my version 3.11

Comment: Of course you need to `import gc`.

Comment: In the first case, one object happened to be allocated in the same memory address as another one (which had already been garbage collected) and therefore had the same id. There's no guarantee that this will happen. The extra allocations added by the f strings changed this behavior.

Comment: [Please don't just delete and repost your questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76919821/do-f-strings-change-the-objects-id)

Comment: @interjay but how gc collects the first object meanwhile it has reference varr 'a'?

Comment: @user2357112 pls look carefully - they are 2 principial different questions,I had mistake there so I deleted it

Comment: Looks like the same question; you could simply have edited the original one.

Comment: @cardinal2000 `a` is just the id of the first object, not the object itself. The object can be garbage collected even if `a` exists.

Comment: @ 9769953 tnx for prompt

Comment: @interjay pls see attached link 'Every Python object has a reference count, also known as a refcount. The refcount is a tally of the total number of other objects that hold a reference to a given object. When you add or remove references to an object, the number goes up or down. When an object's refcount goes to zero, that object is deallocated and its memory is freed up.
What is a reference? Anything that allows an object to be accessed by way of a name, or by way of an accessor in another object.'https://www.infoworld.com/article/3671673/python-garbage-collection-and-the-gc-module.htm?

Comment: Yes, I know what a reference count is. And as I said, the object returned by `my_decorator(some_func)` doesn't have any references to it after the call to `id` so it can be garbage collected.

Comment: @interjay oh seems like I got u,thank u very much

Comment: How did you get into this situation in the first place? You've got a "decorator" that doesn't return a callable and doesn't use the one passed in, you're getting the ID of an ID (which doesn't really mean anything AFAIK), and you're passing IDs around (which isn't useful AFAIK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of implementation details of standard Python you need to be aware of.  They are interacting to give the behavior you are seeing.  These details might be different in a different Python implementation, or even a future version.  Since they're implementation details they're not guaranteed to stay the same.

First the `id()` of an object is the object's memory address.  Two different objects can have the same id if they coincidentally end up at the same address.  Of course this is impossible if both objects exist at the same time.

Second, objects are garbage collected immediately when there are no more references to them.  Once an object is garbage collected, its memory is available for a new object.

In both cases, your calls to `my_decorator` are creating a new object that is not being assigned to a reference so it will be garbage collected at the end of the statement.  In the first case there's nothing else going on so nothing gets in the way of the second object being allocated at the same place as the first.  In the second case you're creating an f-string which is more work, probably causing some other object to occupy the newly freed space.

Answer (score 2):

The f-strings have nothing to do with it. What you're seeting is undefined behaviour, per the docs for [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object **during its lifetime**. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes **may have the same `id()` value**.

(added bold)

What defines an object's lifetime? [See docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become unreachable they may be garbage-collected.

Specifically, the objects that may have non-overlapping lifetimes are both `wrapper` (which becomes unreachable when `my_decorator` returns) and its ID (which becomes unreachable after calling `id` on it).

Lastly, I should point out that the `func` parameter is unused so `some_func` is also irrelevant.